# Getting a validtion error when trying to apply a Yaml file in AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I'm following along with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-application) tutorial.  I'm at the stage where I deploy using the command:

```
kubectl apply -f azure-vote-all-in-one-redis.yaml
```

The YAML file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  azure-vote-back:
    image: redis
    container_name: azure-vote-back
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"

  azure-vote-front:
    build: ./azure-vote
    image: azure-vote-front
    container_name: azure-vote-front
    environment:
      REDIS: azure-vote-back
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

If I add an apiVersion and a Kind, like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
```

Then I get the error:

```
error validating data: ValidationError(Pod): unknown field "services" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Pod
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The file that you provide is the type of [Docker Compose for multi-container in Azure service Web App for Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app#download-the-sample), not for AKS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to apply a Docker Swarm/Compose YAML file to your Kubernetes cluster. This will not work directly without a conversion.

Using a tool like Kompose to convert your Docker YAML into k8s YAML is a useful step into migrating from one to the other.

For more information see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/

Answer (score 1):

so first of all, every yaml definition should follow AKMS spec: apiVersion, kind, metadata, spec. Also, you should avoid pod and use deployments. Because deployments handle pods on their own.

Here's a sample vote-back\front definition:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-back
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azure-vote-back
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: azure-vote-back
        image: redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-back
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
  selector:
    app: azure-vote-back
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-front
spec:
  replicas: 3
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 60%
      maxUnavailable: 60% 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: azure-vote-front
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: azure-vote-front
        image: aksrg.azurecr.io/azure-vote-front:voting-dev
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: REDIS
          value: "azure-vote-back"
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom: {fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.namespace}}
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: k8s
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-front
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: azure-vote-front
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am deploying my project on GKE via Travis. In my travis file, I am calling a shell file (deploy.sh).

In the deploy.sh file, I have written all the steps to create kubernetes resources:

```
### Deploy

# Apply k8s config
kubectl apply -f .
```

So here, I replaced `kubectl apply -f .` with the individual file names as follows:

```
### Deploy

# Apply k8s config
kubectl apply -f namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
```

And then, the error is fixed!