# YAML - Validation error during deployment using Yaml config file

Tags: azure, kubectl, azure-aks, yaml-cpp

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli) Microsoft Tutorial to create a Windows Server container on an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster using Azure Cli. In the [Run the Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli#run-the-application) section of this turorial, I get the following error when running the following command to deploy the application using `YAML` config file:

```
kubectl apply -f sample.yaml
```

> > error: error validating "sample.yaml": error validating data: apiVersion not set; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

**Question**: As shown in the following `sample.yaml` file, the `apiVersion` is already set. So what this error is about and how can we fix the issue?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample
  labels:
    app: sample
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: sample
      labels:
        app: sample
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": windows
      containers:
      - name: sample
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 800M
          requests:
            cpu: .1
            memory: 300M
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: sample
```

Comment: I'd assume this is due to the mispaste from the browser, check for hidden symbols, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. The issue was related to copy/paste to `Azure Cloud Shell`. When you copy/paste content to `vi` editor in Azure Cloud Shell and if the content's first letter happens to be `a` then following may happen:

when opened vi in read mode, then by pasting, the first `a` may put user in edit mode and may not actually get that `a` inserted in the editor. So, in my case the content was pasted as follows (I'm only showing the first few lines here for brevity). So you notice here `a` was missing in the first line `apiVersion: apps/v1` below:

**sample.yaml file**:

```
piVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
…..
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use an outdated **[`kubectl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/)**. Can you try updating to 1.2.5 or 1.3.0 and run it again

Comment: I'm using `Azure Cloud Shell` that has `Kubectl` already installed (probably by Microsoft). I assume they have the latest version installed. Or may be not. How do I find out the Kubectl version in Azure Cloud Shell? I followed the first paragraph of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli#connect-to-the-cluster) section of the tutorial.

Comment: run kubectl version

Comment: I'm getting the following output. How do I upgrade to the latest version? `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.8", GitCommit:"1da9875156ba0ad48e7d09a5d00e41489507f592", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-14T05:19:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701151/how-to-upgrade-kubectl-client-version

Comment: It seems Microsoft keeps their Azure Cloud Shell tools updated as explained in the second checkmark [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/cloud-shell/). And as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55583899/1232087) we do not need to install the kubectl for AKS if you use the Azure Cloud Shell, that's a default tool installed in it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in my case! For more context, feel free to visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67396205/14619383).

Summary:

If there is any file in which you are applying the yaml configs as follows:

```
kubectl apply -f .
```

then change that to the following:

```
kubectl apply -f namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
```

Basically, apply configs separately with each file.