# Getting an error in applying yaml file to aks ingress controller

Tags: yaml, azure-aks

I'm trying to implement wallarm a security service to a simple API i created in aks ingress controller.

[image: when I add these details to the yaml file and apply this I got an error like this]

I'm getting an error like this
error: error validating ".\values.yaml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

I want this error to go away and apply this.

Comment: This will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428041/yaml-validation-error-during-deployment-using-yaml-config-file)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is this yaml file should be added to the cloud manually. using this.

```
Created the values.yaml file 
vi values.yaml
```

Then You should use server snippets in the annotation of your ingress manifests, not in the values. yaml of the ingress.